# xparse creates infinite loop

Tags: tables, errors, xparse

this MWE creates on my machine a infinite loop. Can someone explain to me why?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,xparse}
    \NewDocumentCommand\hlineX{ m O{0pt} O{#2} }{%
        \specialrule{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        1    & 2    & 3 \\
        \hlineX{1pt}
        4    & 5    & 6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In my main document I created I get different errors:
`"Misplaced \noalign. [    E]"`
`"Missing } inserted. [    E]"` and so on. It's very like the MWE but with more packages loaded.

When I use the `\specialrule` command without `xparse` it works just fine..

Comment: you can not hide a tabular rule inside a robust command with optional arguments. There is then  code before the \noalign which is not allowed there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems the `\hlineX` should be expandable, since a simplified example will cause the same problem.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,xparse}
\protected\def\xline{\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        1    & 2    & 3 \\
        \xline
        4    & 5    & 6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The expandable variant of `\NewDocumentCommand` is `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`, and since it defines expandable new command, the argument specification should not end with optional arguments. Therefore we have the following working example, with the syntax of `\hlinex` modified:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,xparse}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\hlineX{ O{0pt} O{#1} m }{%
        \specialrule{#3}{#1}{#3}%
    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        1    & 2    & 3 \\
        \hlineX[1pt][2pt]{1pt}
        4    & 5    & 6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using TeX now for little more then a year and am still learning. There are so many little details.

Answer (score 8):

The answer of muzimuzhi Z shows what you should do to avoid the error (and you should probably accept that one) but your actual question asks why it loops rather than how to avoid the error.

The looping isn't really related to xparse other than looking for an optional argument is not allowed before `\specialrule` (or `\hrule` or `\multicolumn` or `\rowcolor` or similar special table cell commands) If any non-expandable material is seen the cell template starts and it is too late to insert the non-aligned material for the rule.

So a simpler example of the loop is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}


\tracingall
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        1    & 2    & 3 \\
        \relax\specialrule{0pt}{0pt}{1pt}
        4    & 5    & 6 \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

As in your example this stops with several essentially spurious error messages but if you scroll past them you eventually hit a tight loop and will have to kill the program, `\tracingall` will show:

```
.
.
.
\par ->
{\hrule}

\par ->
{\hrule}

\par ->
{\hrule}
.
.
.
```

Which shows that essentially you have hit this well known loop condition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{\let\par\relax x\hrule}

\end{document}
```

Which makes TeX run forever with no error.

`\hrule`, which makes a horizontal line across the page is only allowed between paragraphs, in vertical mode. If it is encountered in horizontal mode TeX does not raise an error it inserts `\par` to end the current paragraph before the `\hrule` token then proceeds as normal.

The thing to note is that unlike the similar situation of a vertical box ending in horizontal mode, TeX does not execute the primitive end-paragraph code, it literally inserts the token `\par` into the input stream.

So if as here (and for technical reasons in latex tabular) `\par` is locally defined to do nothing then `\hrule` triggers insertion of `\par` which does nothing, then the `\hrule` is seen again, which inserts `\par`....

Comment: Ah, the magic `\par` token .... not perhaps the most brilliant plan in TeX

Comment: @JosephWright no, that accolade goes to `\outer`

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I'm satisfied. I try further hacking with this and see what's happening.